# Which exchanges still support USD account-to-account (A2A) transfers?

Tags: exchanges, account-to-account

Now that Mt. Gox no longer offers MTG USD redeemable codes, what other exchanges offer these vouchers / redeemable codes / coupons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to AML regulations, few exchanges offer this service which is typically considered a banking function.

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/A2A_Transfer_Methods

This functionality can be emulated at exchanges that have integrated a Ripple gateway.  [BITSTAMP](http://www.BITSTAMP.net) is one such exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly whay you are looking for, but might satisfy your use case.

[LocalBitcoins.co](http://localbitcoins.com)m is offering coupon functionality where LocalBitcoins.com users can issue their own coupons. Coupons are paper coupons which the users can print themselves and then sell e.g. in net cafe for cash. Bitcoins are substracted from the issuer walet when the coupon is redeemed. The coupon model is based on [Easy Wallet](https://easywallet.org/) functionality which you may be already familiar with.

Example coupon below:

[image: LocalBitcoins.com demo bitcoin redeemable coupon]

The functionality is currently available for limited audience on LocalBitcoins.com site.